# XML Parsing Broken-up Text

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri, wordml

I'm looking to parse a word document XML to get the footer information per each paragraph, sentence, or phrase.

This command gets all the text without spaces in between.

```
pry(main)> doc.header_and_footers_xml[1].text()
=> " PAGE 1FirstGoogle.comSomething privacy Saturday, February 23, 2019"
```

This command is a little bit better but breaks up the text in weird ways:

```
pry(main)> doc.header_and_footers_xml[1].search('//text()')
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf0eb0c3a4 " PAGE ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf10c41b78 "1">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf0eaa427c "F">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf0ea60bbc "irst">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf0e9f9bc4 "Google.com">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf0f6b636c "Something privacy">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf0b9ded90 " Saturday, February 23, 2019">]

pry(main)> doc.header_and_footers_xml[1].search('//text()')[2]
=> #(Text "F")

pry(main)> doc.header_and_footers_xml[1].search('//text()')[3]
=> #(Text "irst")
```

I would like to receive iterate through a list/array with elements: 'PAGE', '1', 'First', 'Google.com', 'Something privacy', 'Saturday, February 23, 2019'

Below is the entire XML. Is it possible just to iterate on `name = "p"` elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:hdr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:sdt>
        <w:sdtPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:id w:val="-157074914" />
            <w:docPartObj>
            <w:docPartGallery w:val="Page Numbers (Top of Page)" />
            <w:docPartUnique />
            </w:docPartObj>
        </w:sdtPr>
        <w:sdtEndPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
            </w:rPr>
        </w:sdtEndPr>
        <w:sdtContent>
            <w:p w:rsidR="00140C14" w:rsidRDefault="00140C14" w:rsidP="00AD16D8">
                <w:pPr>
                    <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
                    <w:framePr w:wrap="none" w:vAnchor="text" w:hAnchor="margin" w:xAlign="right" w:y="1" />
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
                    </w:rPr>
                </w:pPr>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
                </w:r>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> PAGE </w:instrText>
                </w:r>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
                </w:r>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                            <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
                        <w:noProof />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>1</w:t>
                </w:r>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="PageNumber" />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
    <w:p w:rsidR="002132D5" w:rsidRDefault="00140C14" w:rsidP="00140C14">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
            <w:ind w:right="360" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>F</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="002132D5">
            <w:t>irst</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00140C14" w:rsidRDefault="00140C14" w:rsidP="00140C14">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
            <w:ind w:right="360" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
        <w:t>Google.com</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00140C14" w:rsidRDefault="00140C14" w:rsidP="00140C14">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Header" />
            <w:ind w:right="360" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Something privacy</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="00710468">
            <w:t xml:space="preserve"> Saturday, February 23, 2019</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack" />
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
    </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

Here is the word document:

[image: actual layout in Word document]

Comment: You did not define what the wanted result is. Please post a screenshot of the text as it appears in the word document and also the exact plaintext you want to extract from that.

Comment: Switch on formatting marks ( ¶ ) in Word so things are easier to see. Also, showing a formatted sample of the actual XML might be easier to read than the Nokogiri tree dump.

Comment: The result I want is an array with elements: PAGE 1, First, Google.com, Something privacy, Saturday, February 23 2019.

Comment: great idea re: looking at the actual XML!

Comment: the actual XML also doesn't seem straight forward to parse, is it just me?

Comment: When you post *the entire thing* and not only the relevant part, and when you post it without any format, yes, then it's harder to parse. That's not quite what I had in mind though. Also, the request for a screenshot wasn't completely random. WordML is complex and doing what you want might be harder than you imagine. For example, if part of the text is right-aligned, there won't be any space characters inbetween (this is what you see in your first code sample). Being able to see which parts of the XML correspond to what parts on the screen helps to figure this out.

Comment: @Tomalak screenshot and parsed xml added!

Comment: That's much better, thanks. That gave me something to tinker with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is like this:

1. Define namespace URIs, so we can search for `<w:p>` elements properly with XPath. In this case only the `w:` namespace is relevant.
2. Iterate the `<w:p>` nodes
3. Join the non-empty text nodes in each of them

This is probably horribly non-idiomatic Ruby, but it should get you started:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

header_and_footers_xml = Nokogiri::XML(open("footer.xml"))  

namespaces = {
  "w" => "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
}

paras = header_and_footers_xml.search('//w:p', namespaces)
paras.each do |p|
  nodes = p.xpath('.//text()[normalize-space()]')
  texts = nodes.map { |n| n.text }
  puts(texts.join)
end
```

This prints ([tested on Ruby 2.5](https://repl.it/repls/UnawareFormalModel)):

```
 PAGE 1
First
Google.com
Something privacy Saturday, February 23, 2019
```

The XPath expression `.//text()[normalize-space()]` collects all text nodes (`text()`) descendant of the current node (`.`) and filters out the blank ones by calling `normalize-space()` on each of them, which trims off the whitespace - only those nodes are returned, where a non-empty string remains after trimming.